# seriesの１要素の中にカンマ区切りで含まれる多数のdict書式のデータの取り出し方

Tags: python, numpy

いちおう動作は出来ているのですが、何かもっと簡潔にできる（ループを使わない）方法があれば、知りたいと思っています。

ser_target = ['code', [{'key_1': data_00, 'data_01': 'k_1:data_02'}, {'key_2': data_10, 'data_11': 'k_2:data_12'},・・・, {'key_n': data_n0, 'data_n1': 'k_n:data_n2'}}]

のような、１つの要素の中に、{}でくくられた、見た目は辞書型のような書式で書かれたデータがカンマ区切りで定義されているデータがあります。
つまり、{'key_1': data_00, 'data_01': 'k_1:data_02'}, から {'key_n': data_n0, 'data_n1': 'k_n:data_n2'}　までが、'code'に対する１要素というデータ。

```
lst_code = [
                {'key_1': data_00, 'data_01': 'k_1:data_02'},
                {'key_2': data_10, 'data_11': 'k_2:data_12'},
                ・・・,
                {'key_n': data_n0, 'data_n1': 'k_n:data_n2'}
]
```

というようなに辞書型データを要素とする、リスト変換するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

現状は、文字列検索のループでやっています。

```
top = 0
for i in range(0, len(str_Target)):
    top = str_Target.find('{', top)
    if top < 0:
        break
    end = str_Target.find(r'}', top + 1) + 1
    dict_item = ast.literal_eval(str_Target[top:end])
    lst_result.append(dict_item)
    top = end + 1
```

Comment: `ser_target =` の行は何を表してるのでしょう？ 変数への代入ができてるなら(回答出てる通り) `ser_target[1]` で取り出せるはず。代入文のように見える ような文字列, ということであれば, `find('{')` とか正規表現とか使うことになるでしょう

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。とりいそぎ、お礼まで。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問記事の`ser_target =`の定義は、最後の方の閉じ括弧がtypoか何かで正しくなっていません。
`'k_n:data_n2'}}]`の最後の1つ前の閉じ括弧は`}`ではなく`]`ですね。
以下のようになるはずです。

```
ser_target = ['code', [{'key_1': data_00, 'data_01': 'k_1:data_02'}, {'key_2': data_10, 'data_11': 'k_2:data_12'}, {'key_n': data_n0, 'data_n1': 'k_n:data_n2'}]]
```

辞書データの元の`ser_target`リスト内での位置(index)が決まっている(質問記事で言えば2つ目(indexは1))なら以下で抽出できると思うのですが。

```
lst_code = ser_target[1]
```

`ser_target`リストの中にはどのような仕様/順番でどのようなデータが入っているか定義されていますか？

あるいは定義されていなくて、最初に見つかった辞書のリストを取得するといった形であれば、以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
lst_code = []
for i in range(len(ser_target)):
    value = ser_target[i]
    if type(value) is not list:
        continue
    element = value[0]
    if type(element) is not dict:
        continue
    lst_code = value
    break
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。とりいそぎ、お礼まで。